# Avoiding object slicing and using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

Now I'm developing a searching node program. My code is below and I actually want to search a specific child node. To avoid object slicing, I used a pointer, but the pointer is null_ptr maybe. So how should I avoid this problem. I'm not sure its problem? And to avoid *new instance* attribute, *Parent obj* instance in main() should be declared as shared_ptr supported since c++11?

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 class Parent {
   public:
     Parent() { name = "Parent"; }
     virtual void print() {
       cout << "Parent::print()" << endl;
     }

     string name;
 };

 class Child1 : public Parent {
   public:
     Child1() { name = "Child1"; }
     virtual void print() override{
       cout << "Child1::print()" << endl;
     }
 };

 class Child2 : public Parent {
   public:
     Child2() { name = "Child2"; }
     virtual void print() override{
       cout << "Child2::print()" << endl;
     }
 };

 class Manager {
   public:
     void getChild(int i, Parent* obj) {
       if(i==0) {
         cout << "sest child1" << endl;
         obj = (&child1);
       } else {
         cout << "sest child2" << endl;
         obj = (&child2);
       }
     }
     Child1 child1;
     Child2 child2;
 };

 int main()
 {
   // object slicing?
   // Parent obj;
   // Manager manager;
   // manager.getChild(1, obj);
   // obj.print();

   Parent* obj;
   Manager manager;
   manager.getChild(1, obj);
   obj->print();

 }
```

My code is broken because of segmentation fault.

```
  $ a.out D
    sest child2
    [1]    5457 segmentation fault  ./work/derived/a.out D
```

Comment: You'd need to pass the address of the pointer to `getChild` i.e pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
void getChild(int i, Parent* obj)
```

This function signature is telling us that the function takes an integer and pointer to an object. Both are passed by value:

If you have an object, say at address 42, then you would effectively pass the number 42 as second parameter.

Inside the function the parameters act as variables, and since they're not const in this case, you can modify them. So when you wrote

```
obj = &child1;
```

you only changed the state of a local variable, say from the aforementioned 42 to some other address, e.g. 24. None of this is affecting the pointer the caller gave as second parameter.

What you wanted to achieve is having an "out" parameter. For that you need a pointer to the thing you want to change. In your case you want to change a pointer, so you need a pointer to a pointer:

```
void getChild(int i, Parent * * obj_ptr)
```

To set it to a value, you need to dereference it:

```
*obj_ptr = &child1;
```

**But** in this case I wouldn't use an out parameter, since you're able to return a value from functions, so just return the pointer:

```
Parent* getChild(int i) {
  // ...
  return &child1;
}
// in main
Parent* node = manager.getChild(1);
```

**concerning `std::shared_ptr`:** You should think about who owns the instances your pointers point to. That is, who is responsible of destructing them and freeing the associated memory. In your case the child instances are part of the manager instance. So the manager instance owns them and will take care of them. A `shared_ptr` is for the (hopefully) rare cases when you don't exactly know how long the instance is needed. So you share the ownership, making the last owner responsible of destructing and freeing.

What kind of ownership you actually need here is not entirely clear to me. Do you want some kind of traversal, I.e. are the child instances parents (or managers in your terminology) of other children? Or do you just need access to the members? Then I wouldn't use pointers at all but references.

Comment: Thank you! I realized it using double pointer. Although my example getChild return void, actual code returns boolean to check function result. Are there any demerits if I use double pointer not return pointer directly?

Comment: Is the boolean return value coupled to the validity of the pointer? That is, is it some "found" flag? Then I'd return the pointer and indicate a not found by returning `nullptr`. Otherwise out parameters work great, only they're sometimes a bit clumsy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the pointer `obj` to `getChild` by value (taking a copy).  If you change the local `obj` pointer to point to a different object that doesn't change `obj` pointer in the main scope.  The `obj` pointer in the main scope still points to garbage.

As `obj` is an out parameter a more idiomatic way of writing `getChild` would be to use a return value:

```
Parent* getChild(int i) {
  if(i==0) {
    cout << "sest child1" << endl;
    return &child1;
  }
  cout << "sest child2" << endl;
  return &child2;
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
Manager manager;
auto obj = manager.getChild(1);
obj->print();
```

And no, you shouldn't use a `shared_ptr` for `obj` in the main scope.  At least not as it is written now. Currently,  `child1` and `child2` are owned by `Manager` as they are by-value member variables. You don't want anyone else deleting them other than `Manager`.

But perhaps that was not the design you intended. Perhaps you intended something more like the [Prototype Pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/?title=Prototype_pattern) where `getChild` returns a clone of `child1` or `child2` which should be owned by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't allocate child1 and child2 on stack , rather you should allocated it on head using new operator .Second modification would be to user pointer to pointer while getting any new memory allocation in some different function , Modified program is below :

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>

 using namespace std;

  class Parent {
         public:
                  Parent() { name = "Parent"; }
                       virtual void print() {
                                  cout << "Parent::print()" << endl;
                                       }

                            string name;
                             };

 class Child1 : public Parent {
        public:
                 Child1() { name = "Child1"; }
                      virtual void print() {
                                 cout << "Child1::print()" << endl;
                                      }
                       };

 class Child2 : public Parent {
        public:
                 Child2() { name = "Child2"; }
                      virtual void print() {
                                 cout << "Child2::print()" << endl;
                                      }
                       };

 class Manager {
        public:
                 Manager()
                          {
                                 child1 = new Child1;
                                     child2 = new Child2;
                                          }
                      void getChild(int i, Parent** obj) {
                                 if(i==0) {
                                              cout << "sest child1" << endl;

                                                 *obj = child1;
                                                        } else {
                                                                     cout << "sest child2" << endl;

                                                                         *obj = child2;
                                                                                }
                                      }
                           Child1 *child1;
                                Child2 *child2;
                                 };

 int main()
     {

            Parent* obj;
               Manager manager;
                  manager.getChild(1, &obj);
                     obj->print();

                      }
```

Comment: What is the benefit of allocating `child1` and `child2` using `new` in this case?

Comment: To avoid passing address object allocated on stack in function.

Comment: The objects are allocated on the stack as member variables on the `Manager` so there should be no problem returning their address. If you allocate with `new` then you need to decide who is going to take responsibility to `delete` them. As you have written it noone is taking that responsibility and you are leaking memory.

Comment: Thats true Chris, Program is having memory leak . I just answered this to provide quick resolution to crash .If I were to write such programs , I would have used smart pointers.